# UIView reloaded after clicking a textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to make a very simple login page. Everything is fine, until I started doing some animations.

When I click login button, I move the logo 100px to the top, then I show the inputs.

That worked correctly, but when I click the textfield to edit it, the image (logo) returns to its original position!

My code:

```
  @IBAction func LoginClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
        var center = self.logoImage.center
        center.y -= 100
        self.logoImage.center = center
        self.usernameInput.hidden=false
        self.passwordInput.hidden=false
        self.usernameLine.hidden=false
        self.passwordLine.hidden=false
        self.slidesImg.hidden=true
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto Layout is running and placing your logo back to where the constraints say it should be.  Instead of modifying the frame by changing the center, you should create an `IBOutlet` to the vertical space constraint and then update the `constant` property to move your logo up.

To create the `IBOutlet`, first click on the vertical bar that represents the vertical constraint in the Storyboard.  Then <kbd>control</kbd>-click on the constraint and drag to your viewController code.  Give it a name like `topSpace`.

---

[image: wire up vertical constraint]

---

You'll need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` to animate the constraint change:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func LoginClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    topSpace.constant -= 100
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
        self.logoImage.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.usernameInput.hidden=false
        self.passwordInput.hidden=false
        self.usernameLine.hidden=false
        self.passwordLine.hidden=false
        self.slidesImg.hidden=true
    })
}
```